# Component for showing/picking value from a interval with description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-controls, intervals

Do you know any HTML component for showing/picking value from interval with word description. Similar to [image: this pic] - with showed/picked value and its description ?

Comment: Just create one for yourself using html, css and javascript/jquery

Comment: Yeah, but question is if its already done. I don't want to waste my time to developing things that are (maybe) already done in good quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, there is none suitable component right now. I created one based on this 
[Rainbow Slider](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#styling-rainbow). The example shows everything its needed (JS,CSS).